# Show that A ⊆ N is semi-calculable if and only if there is a Σ-formula φ(x) such that φ defines A.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computability, foundations

I am working through "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen, and am currently stuck on this exercise:

**Show that A ⊆ N is semi-calculable if and only if there is a Σ-formula φ(x) such that φ defines A.**

Here, semi-calculable is defined informally as "there is a computer program P such that if a ∈ A, program P returns 0 on input $a$, and if $a  \not \in A$, program P does not halt when given input $a$."

I tried two things so far: first I tried to use the fact that a set is semi-calculable iff it is weakly representable. But having a formula $\psi$ that weakly-represents $A$ doesn't seem to be helpful as we know nothing about it.

I also tried the fact that $A$ is listable, but again, it did not lead anywhere.

Any hint will be highly appreciated!

Comment: @RobArthan edited

Comment: Do you have access to the fact that a formula is $\Sigma$ iff it is equivalent to a formula of the form $\exists y \varphi(x,y)$ where $\varphi$ is computable (or I guess “calculable” in this terminology)?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen No, I do not have that - but I can see how it will be helpful